# Prevent FormatException when using TextChanged event

Tags: c#, events, textchanged

I'm using TextChanged Event in order to calculate two textboxes and show the result in a third textbox. However, it already works but when the value of any of the two textboxes changes I got FormatException 'Input string was not in a correct format'.
Here is my code:

```
private void txtCustActualDefect_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int TargetDefect = int.Parse(txtCustTargetDfect.Text);
    int ActualDefect = int.Parse(txtCustActualDefect.Text);

    decimal Per = ((decimal)ActualDefect / (decimal)TargetDefect) * 100;
    txtCustPercentageDefect.Text = Per.ToString();
}
```

I know that when altering the value it takes the value of Zero, but how can I prevent that 
any thoughts I would appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/zf50za27%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Which would return `true` if the cast passes.

```
                 int TargetDefect;
                 int.TryParse(txtCustTargetDfect.Text, out TargetDefect);

                 int ActualDefect;
                 int.TryParse(txtCustActualDefect.Text, out ActualDefect);
```

A more safer implementation could be:

```
            int TargetDefect;
            int ActualDefect;

            if(int.TryParse(txtCustTargetDfect.Text, out TargetDefect) && int.TryParse(txtCustActualDefect.Text, out ActualDefect))
            {
                decimal Per = ((decimal) ActualDefect/(decimal) TargetDefect)*100;
                txtCustPercentageDefect.Text = Per.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: John Thank you so much I'm really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

The value of a TextBox's Text property can never be `null`, but it can be `String.Empty`, i.e. an empty string.

Parsing an empty string or any other string that cannot read as an integer will result in an exception thrown.

You can use `TryParse` to try and parse the string without the chance of an exception:

```
int actualDefect;
bool result = int.TryParse(txtCustActualDefect.Text, out actualDefect);
```

If result is `true`, the conversion succeeded; if `false` it failed:

```
if (result)
{
    // The conversion was succesful
}
else
{
    // The conversion has failed
}
```